# Program freezes in nested loop at page.evaluate - Puppeteer - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am new to puppeteer, I wrote a program to automatically select an option from a drop-down list for me. but it is freezing as soon as it gets to the second loop. I have tried removing the await, and swapping the return statement out for an array, to no avail (code is below). How do I fix this? Thanks! :)
PS: Let me know if you need the whole code :)

```
var numDays = await page.evaluate(() => { //INIT DATAS
    return document.getElementsByClassName("input")
        .length;
});
console.log(numDays);
var selected = "";
for (var i = 0; i <
    numDays; i++) { // # of days signup loop
    var numOptions = await page.evaluate(i => { //INIT DATAS
        return document.getElementsByClassName("input")[i].options.length;
    }, i); //init data for numOptions loop
    for (var j = 1; j <
        numOptions; j++) { // 17x options loop | Find study hall option loop
        var result = await page.evaluate(i => {
            return document.getElementsByClassName("input")[i].options[j].value;
        }, i, j);
        var resultTxt = await page.evaluate(i => {
            return document.getElementsByClassName("input")[i].options[j].text;
        }, i, j);
        if (resultTxt.toLowerCase()
            .indexOf('study hall') != -1 || resultTxt.toLowerCase()
            .indexOf('catch up on work') != -1) {
            selected = result;
        } //choose study hall option
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the html and a bit more code so we can reproduce this? :D

Comment: A few observations, although as @Md.AbuTaher said, we’d need to see the HTML and the context: in the second loop, all the functions to evaluate are referring to a different (probably non-existent) `j`, since you pass it to `evaluate` but the functions only expect `i`. Second, you say it freezes on the second loop; how do you know this? If you replace the body of the second loop, does it still freeze? Third, it seems like you could combine the two functions to evaluate and check the result in a single `evaluate` call.

Comment: Aankhen should've submitted his comment as answer instead :D

Comment: I will edit my answer to give credit to Aankhen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found out the issue to the problem... Turns out that I am not importing j correctly in the two page.evaluates. (really silly problem, but it is now fixed:)

Thank you Aankhen for helping me figure out the issue :) I can mark your post as an answer if you post. Just let me know!